# How do I add an interface to a class hierarchy that doesn't already include TInterfacedObject?

Tags: delphi, interface

The following example shows how to start coding against interfaces:

from

```
TMyObject = class
  function Add(a, b: integer): integer;
end;
```

to

```
IInterface = interface
  ['{BFC7867C-6098-4744-9774-35E0A8FE1A1D}']
  function Add(a, b: integer): integer;
end;

TMyObject = class (TInterfacedObject, IInterface 
  function Add(a, b: integer): integer;
end;
```

but how can I manage if the class has an ancestor, let say TMyClassDerivedDirectlyFromTObjectSoItsGotNothingInItAtAll for instance ?

```
TMyObject = class(TMyClassDerivedDirectlyFromTObjectSoItsGotNothingInItAtAll)
    function Add(a, b: integer): integer;
end;
```

Comment: Just a tip: your question doesn´t have much to do with dependency injection of mocking, but with interfaces, so I guess you would be more successful on receiving answers if you tag it with **interface**.

Comment: You are right. Fixed.

Comment: Don't call your own interfaces IInterface, it gives name-collision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I would rename the interface:

```
IMyAddFunction = interface
  ['{BFC7867C-6098-4744-9774-35E0A8FE1A1D}']
  function Add(a, b: integer): integer;
end;
```

If the ancestor already implements IInterface it's not hard:

TTable  inherits from TComponent that already implements the (existing) IInterface for you.
So you could just do:

```
TMyObject = class(TTable, IMyAddFunction)
    function Add(a, b: integer): integer;
end;
```

If not then you have to implement IInterface yourself:

```
IInterface = interface
  ['{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
  function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
  function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
  function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
end;
```

Delphi comes with sources so you could look at the implementation of implementation of TComponent and implement the methods referenced in the answer AlexSC gave .

Comment: How do you know that it's the same `TTable`? My `TTable` doesn't implement `IInterface`. What's more, the implementation in `TComponent` is very different from that in `TInterfacedObject`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I guess not every TTable inherits from TComponent, I thought he was talking about the TTable packaged with delphi.

Comment: I get the sense that the question is of general nature. It just happened that the class was named `TTable`, but it could have been `TMyClassDerivedDirectlyFromTObjectSoItsGotNothingInItAtAll`.

Comment: So the answer would be: look if the ancestor already implements IInterface otherwise, implement it yourself.

Comment: Yes, the question is of general nature. If the ancestor does not implement IInterface already, where can I find more details on how to make the right one ?

Comment: @PieterB Even if the class already implemented it, you might well need to change the implementation

Answer (score 6):

When you have a class implementing an interface, this class has to provide three methods: **_AddRef**, **_Release** and **QueryInterface**. If you look at **TInterfacedObject** code, you will notice those methods there. In fact, **TInterfacedObject** only exists to make it easier to create new interface implementor classes.

If you can´t inherit your new class from **TInterfacedObject**, you have to provide those methods yourself. You can copy **TInterfacedObject** implementations to your class, for instance, then your class will be an interface implementor.